# how to encode javascript and html code which is written in .php file

Tags: javascript, php

Is it possible to encode JavaScript and HTML code (such as the following) which is written in a `.php` file?

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
    function for_sale(){
        $.ajax({    
            type: "POST",
            url: "report/approve/check_status.php",
            data: '&stock_id='+format_stock_id,
            success: function(response) {
                ...
            }
        });     
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: Why would you want to encode the code?

Comment: What do you *mean* by "encode"?

Comment: when we press CRTL+u then we see all javascript code. I want to hide or encode the javascript code

Comment: I want to encode the code because everyone can see the url path written in ajax call and can easily track the URL of server and hence security will be lost

Comment: you could obfuscate it but not encode it

Comment: But i Dont want to use  ofuscate. iwant code which should be written in code itself.

Comment: If not possible then please tell me alternative option to bring security in our javascript code especially in ajax call.?

Comment: These question is already answered please use the below steps      http://stackoverflow.com/a/42952848/7751463

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this has been asked before. Please refer to the link below

[Encrypt HTML Source Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834455/how-to-encrypt-html-source-code-output-using-php)

Comment: Or you can read this http://scriptasylum.com/tutorials/encode-decode.html

Comment: +1 for the link for greenhatman