# How to encrypt page source of a webpage

Tags: javascript, html

I came across this website https://domain-4-sale.firebaseapp.com/demo/index-03.html# and they have encrypted their source code when you see page source . I want to know how to do this .

Comment: Just Google "encrypt HTML source code" and you'll see many pages explaining how, plus the drawbacks, such as no Google indexing etc. But remember it's not actual encryption - it won't protect any sensitive data, just slow them down a bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to encrypt HTML source code output using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834455/how-to-encrypt-html-source-code-output-using-php)

Comment: @sampathwijesinghe thats using php . im asking for using javascript ..I hazve mentioned the link also

Answer (score 4):

That is not encryption. It is the result of [`escaping`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape) some content as noted by the use of [`unescape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape) around what you consider to be encrypted content.

You cannot "encrypt" something that the client needs to interpret. Whatever method is used to "unencrypt" this data would be available on the client (user) meaning it would be easily reversible.

Comment: I just want to know how is that done .......cant find out looked at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp

Answer (score 1):

you can't encrypt your HTML output, you can obfuscated it to make it more difficult for a human to understand.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed you, you can only obfuscate (make it more difficult to view) code on the client side. Due to the fact that the browser must be able to get the original HTML back to render it, this means the client (or end-user) is always able revert it back to HTML.

To see how it works, open up your javascript console and type:

`console.log(unescape('data-here'));`

Replacing with the data from the webpage in question, you'll then see all the HTML dumped to your console.

Comment: yes i just want to make code like above website.... if you know how then please mention

Comment: Simply write your web page, use a javascript escaper (http://www.freeformatter.com/javascript-escape.html) and then copy the `document.write(unescape('your-escaped-data-here'));` to your web page in `<script>` tags