# How to encrypt the Vue.js code after compiling the application?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

When I compile my Vue.js application in the 'dist' folder, if I inspect the item in my browser, you can see the entire code of my application with the url or functions, which I don't want to see.

Is there any way to encrypt this code?

Comment: Anything loaded by the client will be able to be inspected. You can see the code for all websites using inspect element.

Comment: I know, but I would like to know if it is possible to encrypt this code, especially hide the API and functions for security reasons.

Comment: take a look at this answer from a similar post - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2834514/9772148

Comment: For security reasons- assume anything on the client is public knowledge and design accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are talking about *obfuscating* your code.

> In cryptography, encryption is the process of transforming information (referred to as plaintext) using an algorithm (called a cipher) to make it unreadable to anyone except those possessing special knowledge, usually referred to as a key. So encryption makes data “unreadable” whereas obfuscation makes it “difficult”.

There are several ways to obfuscate your code. Here's an example: https://blog.jscrambler.com/how-to-protect-your-vue-js-application-with-jscrambler/